# Get profile ID after using commerce_customer_profile_save()

Tags: 7, commerce

Anyone has any idea how to get the profile_id after I created a new profile using [commerce_customer_profile_save](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!customer!commerce_customer.module/function/commerce_customer_profile_save/7)() ?

Apparently this function does not return the new profile object and I don't think it's very safe just to select last inserted profile from the database :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stupid me, it's in the $profile object itself.

```
commerce_customer_profile_save($profile);
$profile->profile_id;
```